# Run Ruby library from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, opalrb

I found a sweet library written in Ruby which I would like to use in my JS application. 
The library is a [regular expression -> NFA conversion library](https://github.com/hackingoff/scanner-generator/blob/master/lib/scanner_generator/thompson_construction.rb) and would fit perfectly for my needs.

Is there a way to call this ruby library and process the output in JavaScript?

Comment: What environment does your JavaScript application run in? Client side embedded in a webpage? Node.js? Classic ASP? Phonegap? Something else?

Comment: It is embedded in a web page at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run it on the back end (and I would guess you are most probably using node for that), you can call it via [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

If you want to run it in a browser, your best bet is to try to transcribe the library using [Ruby Opal](http://opalrb.org/). However, note that Opal is not fully compatible with MRI and you might need to do some tweaking.

I would recommend searching extensively to find a similar javascript library first.